# Django template: Displaying parent and child from the same model

Tags: django, blogs

I am creating a django blog and I have a Comments model that looks like this:

```
class Comment(models.Model):
  content = models.TextField('Comment', blank=False, help_text='Comment * Required', max_length=500)
  post = models.ForeignKey('Post', on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=False, related_name='comments')
  parent = models.ForeignKey('self', null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, related_name='replies')
```

I am attempting to display the replies below the comment using the code below in the template:

```
{% for comment in comments %}
  {{ comment.content }}
  {% for reply in comment.replies.all %}
    {{ reply.content }}
  {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

However, the result of this is the replies get displayed twice. Below the comment they're related to and again by themselves.
What am I doing wrong? Why are the replies getting displayed twice.
Also, the replies only go one level i.e. there can't be a reply to a reply only a reply to a comment.

Comment: can you add the reply model

Comment: There is no reply model, hence:
`parent = models.ForeignKey('self', null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, related_name='replies')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do a checking in your template to not display the replies if they have a parent associated to them (since they'll be displayed inside the parent comment). You could do:

```py
{% for comment in comments %}
  {% if not comment.parent %}
      {{ comment.content }}
      {% for reply in comment.replies.all %}
        {{ reply.content }}
      {% endfor %}
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```